# <Error>: has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, iphone

Below is the error when i'm trying to instal app.

```
<Error>: entitlement 'com.apple.managedconfiguration.profiled-access' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

<Error>: entitlement 'com.apple.private.bmkept.allow' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile
```

I tried the other solutions which are there in other stack overflow answers. But issue persist. I tried removing app and profile from device and re-installed the app again.

This issue is happening only in iPod 4Gen running iOS6. In other devices user is able to install.

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: Did you sign the app with an App Store certificate and install it from Xcode? You might need to use an Ad-Hoc cert or make new ones. Also, check Apple's developer site and make sure the certs are still valid.

Comment: @Dare, thanks for reply. App is signed with certificate. I'm trying to install from switch board. And since certs is a valid one, user is able to install in other devices other than iPod 4Gen. If i'm not wrong.

Comment: There's a very good chance, coming from switchboard, that the app is signed with a distribution profile that only allows the app to run on devices with specific UDIDs that have been added to the developer account. Is the account yours? If it is, and it isn't an enterprise account, you might need to register that specific device with the apple id you're using to sign the app.